# Timer and debug issues of running iOS app on M1 MacOS

Tags: ios, macos, timer, apple-m1

My iOS app runs a repeatable timer inside a main dispatch queue to update the UI screen status periodically. It runs normally on iPhone and iPad. When it runs on a M1 MacOS, the timer seems not functioning as expected - the timer is called much much faster than the defined time interval.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true,
            block: { 
                     // runs code to update UI
            })
}
```

Besides, is there any good way to debug the iOS app running on M1 MacOS (like setting debug breakpoints in XCode) instead of re-installing/upgrading the iOS app from App Store after change each time?

Thank you very much for your advices.

Comment: Yes, try adding an `if self.timer != nil { print("Timer already running")} else { self.timer = ...}` and see what you get

Answer (score 1):

We do not have the broader context in which you are calling the code in your question. Theoretically, there could be some race condition that performs differently on the different machines. Or perhaps when testing on the M1 device, there was a subtle difference in the testing procedure.

Regardless, there are a few defensive programming techniques that can solve this sort of problem:

1. I would make sure that `timer` is `weak` variable. The `RunLoop` will keep a strong reference to the timer for you, so you do not need to keep your own strong reference to it:

   ```swift
   weak var timer: Timer?
   ```

   By doing this, when the timer is invalidated, this reference will be set to `nil` automatically.
2. When creating a timer, `invalidate` the prior timer, if any. This will protect you should you ever accidentally call this routine more than once:

   ```swift
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.timer?.invalidate()   // invalidate prior timer, if any

       self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
           guard let self = self else {
               timer?.invalidate()
               return
           }

           // runs code to update UI
       }
   }
   ```
3. Note that in addition to the `invalidate`-before-scheduling pattern, I also

   - I use `[weak self]` pattern in closure, ensuring that the repeating timer cannot not unintentionally keep a strong reference to the current object.
   - I use `guard let self = self else ...` pattern to `invalidate` the timer and `return` should the object in question be deallocated.

   But the critical note is that we want to use `[weak self]` with repeating timers to guard against strong reference cycles.
4. Optionally, while the above will stop the timer if the object has been deallocated when it next fires, I would generally also explicitly stop the timer as soon as the object is deallocated.

   ```swift
   deinit {
       timer?.invalidate()
   }
   ```

The combination of the above steps will ensure that you can only have one timer per object, regardless of how often you call this routine. These steps will help prevent ever having multiple timers running at the same time.